# GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns with bad information

Tags: c++, windows, iocp

I'm writing a multicast producer and multicast consumer applications using IOCP.  My producer app is multi-threaded and publishes to multiple multicast channels.  Each channel is published on its own thread, so I'm certain there are no synchronization / race condition issues with the send buffers.  In fact, using wire shark, the datagrams look good (with an occasional one being malformed (unsure if this is normal for UDP datagrams)).

My consumer application is where I'm seeing the trouble.  My consumer app is also multithreaded. But again, only a single WSARecv is called for any single multicast channel (each channel has its own set of buffers), so there is only a single thread accessing the buffers.  When my call to GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns, I process the data, then call WSARecv to start the process again.

The problem I see is that GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns with old data in the buffer (I reuse the buffer).  When I write the buffers to a log file, I can see that the data is not changing, though my Wire Shark recordings show the datagrams to be fine.  The intermittent nature of this bug seems to point to a synchronization issue, but I've looked carefully through the library AND I don't see this issue using TCP.  Is there any way that GetQueuedCompletionStatus could return bogus data?

```
bool cont = true;
DWORD xferd;
OVERLAPPED* overlapped = NULL;
TTOverlapped<InternalEndpointPtr>* tto;
ULONG_PTR key;

while (cont) {
    BOOL b = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp_, &xferd, &key, &overlapped, INFINITE);

    // only a single WSARecv called per overlapped structure
    // it's assumed that if overlapped != NULL, WSARecv call has completed
    if (overlapped) {
        tto = static_cast<TTOverlapped<InternalEndpointPtr>*>(overlapped);

        switch (tto->opCode()) {
        case IOCP_OP_CODE_READ: readMessage(tto, xferd); break;
        case IOCP_OP_CODE_WRITE:
            if (xferd == 0)
                std::printf("Send operation failed: %d.\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        case IOCP_OP_CODE_NEW_CLIENT:
            tto->endpoint()->recv();
            delete tto;
            break;
        case IOCP_OP_CODE_SHUTDOWN:
            cont = false;
            break;
        default
            std::printf("Not expecting this: %d!!!\n", tto->opCode());
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        DWORD d = GetLastError();
        if (d != 995)
            Logger::log(LOG_LEVEL_STATUS, LOG_TYPE_SYSTEM, "InternalIpcProcessor::processIocpCallbacks(): GetQueuedCompletionStatus returned FALSE. Thread id = %d. GetLastError = %d.", ::GetCurrentThreadId(), GetLastError());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not using the buffer before the operation has completed are you?

Comment: I haven't used IOCP with sockets before, however I found myself resorting to the NTxxx functions due to similar weirdness with files...

Comment: Please show your actual code. You are likely not managing the buffer correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The solution was to zero the overlapped structure before each send.

Comment: Spoke too soon.  This bug only manifests when sending/receiving a high volume, which was apparently below threshold early today.

Comment: The most obvious potential issue is that you're not checking `b` to tell whether the I/O operation succeeded or not, but there could also be problems in `readMessage` and/or the code that issues the call to WSARecv.  You do need to zero the overlapped structure each time, by the way.